# Why doesn't the controller recognise the data passed on from the model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get data from my DB using a model, to then be used in the view. I return the query results to my controller and it gives me the undefined variable notice.

I tried first tried performing a select(get) statement in the controller, I then defined the result array as row before defining the specific row to be used, to which I pass on to my view. That threw an error, then I tried the same thing but with a model and a return to the controller:

> controller.php

```
public function Home()
{
  $this->load->model('Main');
  $this->Main->getresults();

  $this->load->view('header', $data);
}
```

> model.php

```
public function getresults() {

  $query = $this->db->get('table');
  foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {

    $data = array(
      'column' => $row["column"]
    );
}
return $data;
}

view.php

<?php echo $column; ?>
```

I expect the return of `$data` to the controller for it to be used in the view, yet it still throws a notice of an undefined variable.

Comment: You don't assign the return from getresults to anything in the controller. I'm also unsure that your getresults functionality is right. At the moment, it will only return an array with a single column.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: `$data = $this->Main->getresults();` and for the second bit of my comment, you keep doing `$data = ` in getresults, which overrides the value in the variable, it doesn't add to it.

Comment: indeed, you'd have to either do `$data[] = array(...)` in `getresults`, and to access it you'd also need a `foreach` in the view. based on this code, I think you are going to need to study arrays a bit more as well as the CI docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller you don't assign and send data to view.
Change your code there:

```
public function Home()
{
  $this->load->model('Main');
  $data = $this->Main->getresults();

  $this->load->view('header', $data);
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you, for some reason, it doesn't let me accept for 10 minutes but I will do so when I can!

Comment: Yes, $data can be variable or Array(..)  pass from the controller to view